# input type="radio" with runat="server" ServerChange won't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, htmlcontrols

I am aware that I can user RadioButton web control instead of the input type="radio" with runat="server". However, we are trying to modernize our application and trying to stick with HTML5 generic controls (so that they are easy to migrate when we finally have MVC).

I have radio buttons as bellow.

```html
<input type="radio" name="XYZ" value="abc" id="optabc" runat="server"/>abc<br/>
<input type="radio" name="XYZ" value="def" id="optdef" runat="server"/>def<br/>
<input type="radio" name="XYZ" value="ghi" id="optghi" runat="server"/>ghi<br/>
<input type="radio" name="XYZ" value="jklk" id="optjkl" runat="server"/>jkl<br/>
<input type="radio" name="XYZ" value="mno" id="optmno" runat="server"/>mno<br/>
<input type="radio" name="XYZ" value="pqr" id="optpqr" runat="server"/>pqr<br/>
```

I handle the click event as below.

```html
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            optabc.ServerChange += new System.EventHandler(this.Server_Change);
            optdef.ServerChange += new System.EventHandler(this.Server_Change);
            optghi.ServerChange += new System.EventHandler(this.Server_Change);
            optjkl.ServerChange += new System.EventHandler(this.Server_Change);
            optmno.ServerChange += new System.EventHandler(this.Server_Change);
            optpqr.ServerChange += new System.EventHandler(this.Server_Change);
        }


protected void Server_Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (optabc.Checked)
            //do something
        else if (optmno.Checked)
            //do something
    }
```

I have made sure AutoEventWireup="true". However, Server_Change method never gets executed when radio button is selected.

Comment: Are you clicking a button to cause a postback? or are you expecting it to just happen when you click a radio button?

Comment: expecting it to just happen when clicking a radio button

Comment: That's the problem. Radio buttons don't trigger anything on the server side. You'll need to submit the form for the server to know something changed. There's no `AutoPostBack` when you're not using the ASP.NET Web Controls. You'll need to write JavaScript to submit the form when they click one.

Comment: I tried adding AutopostBack=true attribute, and that didn't work either. e.g. <input type="radio" name="XYZ" value="pqr" id="optpqr" runat="server" AutopostBack=True/>pqr<br/>

Comment: No, my point is you *can't* autopostback. You'd need to use an `<asp:RadioButton>`. What you want to do is something like `document.getElementById('THEIDOFYOURFORM').submit();` of course though, that's going to cause a complete page reload (postback).

Comment: Ok yeah, that did the trick :-). So even if I set  AutopostBack=True for HTMLControls, it won't postback? Can you possibly give me a link to documentation? I'd like to learn this in detail and not just solve a problem.

Comment: There is no AutoPostBack on an HTMLGenericControl. So setting it accomplishes nothing because it doesn't exist. From ASP.NET's perspective, setting <input AutoPostBack="true"> is no different than <input AutoWriteMyApplicationForMe="true">. It will just ignore that attribute and render it to the page because ASP.NET doesn't know what to do with it. There's really no documentation on it, it's just not a feature that exists.